# Selenium- jenkins with Linux. "Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have a maven project working fine with local Jenkins on Windows.
When I try to run the same test from Jenkins set up in LINUX, I am getting Firefox driver error.

selenium code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/geckodriver");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
options.setBinary("/usr/bin/firefox");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);`
```

Error Message:

> Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/bin/firefox
>   Stacktrace:
>   Stacktrace
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/bin/firefox
>           at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:504)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Executable.(Executable.java:43)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.(FirefoxBinary.java:123)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions$Binary.asBinary(FirefoxOptions.java:420)
>           at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.getBinaryOrNull(FirefoxOptions.java:220)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.getBinary(FirefoxOptions.java:216)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
>           at AutomationModules.LaunchBrowser.getDriver(LaunchBrowser.java:37)
>           at Validations.LoginValidation.StartBrowser(LoginValidation.java:26)

I tried not giving any binary files as well. It does not work

Expecting the test to run successfully from Jenkins

Comment: I hate those fake files. ;-)

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/firefox` exist? Is it a file (not a directory)? What happens if you run it?

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 
`/usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh*`
Which starts

```
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

As I haven't changed Frirefox install location, this seems to be the default one, so probably this would work for you, too.
So try

```
options.setBinary("/usr/lib/firefox/firefox");
```